# Imageview xml parser error

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi I had developed one xml parser in a android application.Here the xml is successfully parsed in listview(list of products).Now I had implemented this activity with an intent to another activity.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
int position, long id) {
String Name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
String Category = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist)).getText().toString();
String Price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration)).getText().toString();
String Image=((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_image)).getImageMatrix().toString();

// Starting new intent
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, Name);
in.putExtra(KEY_ARTIST, Category);
in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, Image);
in.putExtra(KEY_DURATION, Price);
startActivity(in);
```

the next activity purpose is user clicking one particular product from list of products that time the next activity have to displayed that particular product details.

the nextactivity is SingleMenuLietItem.java source code is

```
package com.example.truebranches;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingleMenuItemActivity extends Activity {

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_TITLE = "Name";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "Category";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "Image";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "Price";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

// getting intent data
Intent in = getIntent();

// Get XML values from previous intent
String Name = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
String ProductURL = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);
String Image = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);
String Price = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DURATION);


// Displaying all values on the screen
TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
TextView lblProductURL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.producturl_label);
ImageView lblImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_label);
TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_label);

lblName.setText(Name);
lblProductURL.setText(ProductURL);
lblImage.setImageResource(Image);
lblCost.setText(Price);

}
}
```

Here the next activity have to display textview product details..but the image is not displayed ..because i am struggling in this part...so which line i have to change for the   image will be displayed in next activity.here
lblImage.setImageResourse(Image) dis line having error The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (String)...how it is cleared. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

can't you just set the image like when you set the list items images?

i think it isn't working because of this :

```
String Image=((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_image)).getImageMatrix().toString();
```

UPDATE:
use this method to download the image :

```
public void downloadImage(String url, String pictureName) {
        final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    String packageName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
      + getString(R.string.app_name); 

    folder = new File(packageName);
    folder.mkdirs();
    File f = new File(folder, pictureName);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode +
                    " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);

        }

        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // Bug on slow connections, fixed in future release.
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(inputStream));
                 try {
                     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());
                     bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 bm.recycle();
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w("ImageDownload", "I/O error while retrieving bitmap from " + url, e);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w("ImageDownload", "Incorrect URL: " + url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w("ImageDownload", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url, e);
    } finally {
    }
}
```

and in your SingleMenuItemActivity :

```
String  packageName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
            + getString(R.string.app_name);

folder = new File(packageName);
folder.mkdirs();
File f = new File(folder, pictureName);
Bitmap bitmap = null;
if (f.isFile())
    try {
        bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(f.toURL().openStream());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
if (bitmap != null)
    lblImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: i don't know dis method...so please give me solutions..how is it do

Comment: where is the image you want to set in the SingleMenuItemActivity? it is in drawable folder or you have to download it from a link?

Comment: am worked dis link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/...here added dis coding part...The Customized ListView is implemented to Single Menu item....here i wish to get output is when am clicked someone like you product means that time the next activity having that particular someone like you product details displayed.but i don't know how it is do...so please help me